# How is Ubuntu responsible for "competing" with other bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth, android

## Background

I have a [PXC 550](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01E3XLNA0) and it seems to have this *convenient* feature that allows me to have both my PC and phone connected to it simultaneously. Run Ubuntu 18 and Android 8. I haven't yet tested this on Windows but will attempt to soon.

## When  It Works

I'm not sure precisely how it's intended to work, but It does some nice things. For instance, If I'm on my PC listening to audio and recieve a phone call, something tells the headset to switch to phone audio, I can take a call and ideally when it's finished it will return to PC audio. This is very convenient when it works and it works quite often with calls.

## When It Doesn't

Often enough, If I'm perusing the web and listening to audio via PC, my stream may get interupted by an email ping or calendar notifcation on my phone and it may not return back to the PC. Ubuntu's sound manager still indicates it's connected to the device but it seems stuck on the phone even though the notification has passed.

## What fixes it

What I found most weird is that when the above scenario happens, the solution seems to be related to toggeling to **Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)** where you get audio that sounds awful, and then back to **High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)** which returns control back to the PC as normal and sounds much better.

What is going on behind the scenes here and is this likely an issue with Ubuntu, Android or my headset? I'm not really sure how to narrow this down.